# Hide row depending on a html table cell value

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I have a table that displays data from database and i have a cell with a simple arithmetic function.
I want to hide the entire row where the result of the sum  is zero(if $sold value is zero).

```html
<input type="button" id="btnHide" Value=" Hide Empty Rows " />
...
<tbody>
   <?php }
 
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC)) { 
    $sold=$row['value1']+$row['value2']);
    
 { ?>
            <tr>
   <td><?php echo $row['contract'] ?></td>
   <td><?php echo (round($row['value1'], 2)) ?></td>
   <td><?php echo (round($row['value2'],2 )) ?></td>
   <td><?php echo ((round($sold, 2))+0) ?></td>
 </tr><?php } } ?>
    </tbody>
```

I found some code to hide all rows where it have empty cells, but it's not what i want. Thx for help.

```html
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#gdRows td").each(function() {
        var cellText = $(this).text();
        if ($.trim(cellText) == '') {
            $(this).css('background-color', 'cyan');
        }
    });

    $('#btnHide').click(function() {
        $("#gdRows tr td").each(function() {
            var cell = $.trim($(this).text());
            if (cell.length == 0) {
                $(this).parent().hide();
            }
        });
    });
    $('#btnReset').click(function() {
        $("#gdRows tr").each(function() {
            $(this).show();
        });
    });
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add a class to those cells for simplification

```
<td class="sold"><?php echo ((round($sold, 2))+0) ?></td>
```

Then use `filter()`

```
$("td.sold").filter(function() {         
     return +$(this).text().trim() === 0;         
}).parent().hide();
```

---

You could also do the same thing in php by adding a `hidden` class to the row if `$sold` is zero and add a css rule for `hidden` class

PHP

```
<tr class="<?= $sold == 0 ? 'hidden' :'';?>">
```

Answer (score 1):

The following function will loop through all `<tr>` in a table and find the 4th cell within the row. If that cell contains a value that evaluates to zero, then the row becomes hidden.

```js
$("table tr").each(function() {
  var sold = $(this).find(":nth-child(4)");
  if (parseFloat(sold.text()) === 0)
    $(this).hide();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>Contract</td>
    <td>123</td>
    <td>456</td>
    <td>789</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Contract</td>
    <td>123</td>
    <td>456</td>
    <td>0</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Contract</td>
    <td>0.123</td>
    <td>0.456</td>
    <td>0.0</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Contract</td>
    <td>0.123</td>
    <td>0.456</td>
    <td>0.789</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```