# how to hide a table row in html here the condition as row values using javaScript ? If two row values are the same then hide one

Tags: javascript, html

I have a html table where I need to hide one row where column value is same. like if key1 and key2 have same value then hide one row.
    here each row is different, in that there are two dates whose value may be same sometimes in that case i should hide one row. the data are comming in html in json format. here duplicate does not mean that two rows are completely same, no there values are same.

```
<html>
<header>Hide Test</header>
<body>
<pre>
<tr>
<td>Key1</td>
<td>Value1</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Key2</td>
<td>Value2</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Key3</td>
<td>Value3</td>
</tr>

</pre>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: This the same question has asnwered/solved in this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33085499/hide-row-depending-on-a-html-table-cell-value

Comment: This is not a good approach. If you want to filter duplicate entry, Then you should have data in `Javascript Array` then filter duplicate entry then render the array as table. You can use `riot.js` or `vue.js` to do these rendering process easily....

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Hide row depending on a html table cell value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33085499/hide-row-depending-on-a-html-table-cell-value)

Comment: @BanujanBalendrakumar  data is available to html in the form of json like orderItem.orderItem.customerDates.customerRequiredByDate and this data is being used at some other places also. i can not modify this json data.

Comment: @MONSTER but he wants a javaScript solution (not jQuery)..

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the value will always be in the second  field of each row I have a solution here which should work.

```
//we need to check that the window has loaded so we can target the elements in the DOM.
window.onload = function(){
  var seen = [];  
  var tableRows = document.getElementsByTagName('tr');
  for(i = 0; i < tableRows.length; i++){
    //get the table data for this particular table row
    var tableData = tableRows[i].getElementsByTagName('td');
    //the value will be contained in the second td tag of the row so we retrieve it as follows:
    var value = tableData[1].innerText;
    //log the value to check.
    console.log(value);    

    if(seen[value]){
      //if the value already exists hide the table row that contains this value.
      tableRows[i].style.display = "none"; 
    }else{
      //add the value to the 'seen' array.
      seen[value] = true;
    }
  }

}
```

You can test this with the following table where two values are the same.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Hide test</title>
    <script>
      //javascript code goes here
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>

   <table>
     <tr>
      <td>Key1</td>
      <td>Value1</td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
      <td>Key2</td>
      <td>Value2</td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
      <td>Key3</td>
      <td>Value1</td>
     </tr>
    </table>

  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: i put all the above code in a single html file but its not working, do i need to do something else ?

Comment: @KRupesh what errors are you getting? can you check in the console? Did you put the javascript in a <script> tag. Is the html page outputting the whole table?

Comment: @KRupesh I have edited my answer to make the code more clear. insert the javascript code where i've stated in the HTML file.

Comment: @KRupesh if you have more than one table in your html document let me know as I will need to edit the code.

Answer (score 0):

You can loop over all rows, save found values in an array and if a value is already in an array you will hide it instead.

```js
var rows = document.querySelectorAll('table tr');
var foundValues = [];
rows.forEach(function(el){
  console.log(foundValues);
  console.log(el.children[1].innerHTML);
  if(foundValues.includes(el.children[1].innerHTML)) {
    el.style.display = 'none';
  }
  else {
    foundValues.push(el.children[1].innerHTML);
  }
});
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>Key1</td>
    <td>Value1</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Key2</td>
    <td>Value2</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Key3</td>
    <td>Value2</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Key4</td>
    <td>Value4</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```